# Get children in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, javascript-objects

I have this array:

```
myArray: [{
    name: "Name1",
    subArray: [{
        name: "Subname1",
        value: 1
    }]
}, {
    name: "Name2",
    subArray: [{
        name: "Subname2",
        value: 2
    }]
}, {
    name: "Name3",
    subArray: [{
        name: "Subname3",
        value: 3
    }, {
        name: "Subname4",
        value: 4
    }]
}, ]
```

I am using this array in a Vue app, but this should not be vue-specific.

In a dropdown I am showing all the values from the parent array (Name1, Name2, Name3). So far, so good. In Vue I do it like so:

```
<option v-for="array in myArray">
```

But, when the user has selected the parent array, I have another dropdown below, which should show the children of the selected object. So if the user selects Name3, there should be two options in my other dropdown with the two subArray's values.
How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<option v-for="option in myArray[index].subArray">
```

where `index` is index of your first option.